# setting up DNS proxy server

Tags: linux, domain-name-system

Because some websites/repos are blocked in my country (like docker repo)
I want to setup a DNS server in Linux on a VPS outside of my country
so the DNS server proxies my requests to blocked websites. I know how to setup
regular DNS servers using bind. But I couldn't find a good tutorial to setup
a proxy DNS on any kind of linux distros. Can you give me one please?

Comment: DNS queries are likely to be only the tip of the iceberg so to speak.  You may want to look into using a VPN - whether it's your own or a commercially available one.

Comment: Why not just use a DOH endpoint? "proxy DNS" does not really exist. You mean a recursive DNS you can query and that will do the iterations for you from another vantage point than yourself.